# To find dimension of subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Let W be subspace spanned by$ (2i,0,1,2i) , (0,2i-2,i-3,0),  (-i,1,0,i),  (1,1,1,1) $

I have tried to reduce it to RREF , but its such a pain  . Is thereany shorter way i could do this question.thanks

EDIT . I have checked determinant and is equals zero , while 3 by 3 principal minor is non zero so can i conclude dimension equals 3

Comment: if you checked and the determinant is zero then W has dim $\leq 3.$ If in advance there is a 3 times 3 minor not zero, then the matrix formed by the previous vectors have rank 3 and so the row-space (and the column space) of the matrix have dimension 3.

Comment: what is $i$? is it a square root of $-1$?